# background events and editable foreground events in fullcalendar-vue

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar

I'm using the fullcalendar-vue component.  My scenario is event scheduling, where the background events are unavailable timeslots, but you can add events to the calendar in available timeslots.

Two event sources:

1. bound reactive array for events added to calendar when user clicks a date
2. event function to retrieve background events when user clicks next month

How do I set up these two event sources?

```
<FullCalendar editable="true" ref="calendar"
  :header="{
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth, timeGridWeek'
  }"
  :plugins="plugins"
  :weekends="true"
  :event-sources="eventSources"
  @dateClick="handleDateClick"/>

// I have tried adding the event sources as data: and computed:

computed: {
  eventSources: function () {
    return [
      {
        id: "events",
        // this is the array of editable events.
        // how do I access this in @dateClick?
        events: []
      },
      {
        id: "background",
        // these are the background events
        events: (info) => {
          // ... encode start/end dates in URL, send via axios promise ...
          axios.get(url)
            .then(response => {
            var calendarEvents = [];
            // ... load up the array of background events and return them ...
            return calendarEvents;
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
        }
      }
    ];
  }
},

methods:
  handleDateClick: function (item) {
    let calendarApi = this.$refs.calendar.getApi();
    var source = calendarApi.getEventSourceById('events');
    // this is where I'm stuck.  Need to add this event to events[]
    // the following doesn't work because there's no access to the array in the source object
    source.events.push(
    {
      'title': 'New Event',
      'start': item.date,
      'duration': '01:00:00'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the data object for two way binding. Computed properties are functions that are cached based on their reactive dependencies.

You should use methods for fetching data, not computed. You can use created to automatically trigger your function when the component is created.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    selected: '',
    names: []
  },
  computed: {
    sayHello() {
      return 'HELLO ' + this.selected.toUpperCase()
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchData()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.names = ['john doe', 'sam smith', 'bill hicks']
      }, 1000)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div v-if="!names.length">
      <p>Loading...</p>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <label>Select a name</label>
      <select v-model="selected">
        <option selected disabled>Select a name</option>
        <option v-for="name in names" :value="name">{{ name }}</option>
      </select>
      <br />
      <p>{{ sayHello }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Okay, you're suggesting I don't use :event-sources and bind to the reactive :events.  But then how do I load more background events on click next month? :backgroundEvents needs to be a function that return an array, :events is an array.

Comment: Would you be able to add your full markup and script code from the component so I can get a better idea of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I edited the original post and added the full example